# Query by date with ASP and MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I need to make a query in a MySQL database returning records with the current date.

I found the command below and it works perfectly inside MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TBAvaliacoes WHERE DataHora = (Date_Format(Now(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
```

[image]

But when I do this inside ASP, it returns me the error below:

[image]

See how I am doing:

```
' ## LISTA RAMAIS
Set cmdListaAvaliacoes = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmdListaAvaliacoes.ActiveConnection = conn
cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBAvaliacoes WHERE DataHora = (Date_Format("&Now()&",'%Y-%m-%d'))"
response.write cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandText
cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandType = 1
Set rsListaAvaliacoes = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsListaAvaliacoes.Open cmdListaAvaliacoes, , 3, 3
```

If I enclose Now () in single quotation marks, it gives no error, but returns nothing.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Awaiting,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the [Now()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-now/) function defined by MySql then you shouldn't use the VB.NET function and concatenate its output to your sql. Just write the code exactly how you write it in the MySql Workbench

```
cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBAvaliacoes 
                                  WHERE DataHora = (Date_Format(Now(),'%Y-%m-%d'))"
```

If you want to pass a particular date then you need to format your date as expected by MySql

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = new DateTime(2019,8,10)

cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBAvaliacoes 
                                  WHERE DataHora = '" & myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
```

But in this case the better approach is to use parameters (even if you have full control of what your date is)

```
Dim myDate As DateTime = new DateTime(2019,8,10)
cmdListaAvaliacoes.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TBAvaliacoes 
                                  WHERE DataHora = @dat"
Dim prm = cmdListaAvaliacoes.CreateParameter("@dat", adDBDate, adParamInput)
prm.Value = myDate
cmdListaAvaliacoes.parameters.Append prm
```

**Side note**
A lot of time has passed from the last time I have used ADODB. So the parameter solution is how I remember it. Search on the net for more complete [CreateParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-and-createparameter-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-2017) examples

Comment: I'm using Classic ASP. Sorry for don't say this before.
Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: Answer updated with an example both with a formatted string as expected by MySql and with a parameter